# How to multiply two numeric values inside a browser (to calculate prices) without actually refreshing page?

Tags: php, html

My brother has a grocery store. He asked me that if I could create a website to order grocery online so he could get it home delivered.

I know HTML, CSS and a little PHP.

I wanted to ask if anyone would guide how to do calculations on a browser. Like if I am selling mangoes. I will show that price per unit weight. Than I will provide a drop down from where the buyer can choose weight. And just next to it the calculation will occur and he can get the total price he has to pay on the same page.

After that I know what to do.when he presses submit I will take the total and pass it to confirmation page using header command in PHP .

Please note that I its pay on delivery site so I don't need a payment method.

Comment: this can be done using javascript. give us some html code so we can provide you some examples.

Comment: instead of trying to complicate your self, try to write it all on paper, if you can figure out the logic on paper, then you can start thinking about programming it

Comment: thank you so much ........ i am trying to achieve some like this vegoncall.com.

Comment: i dont have any code ready at this time so if you could take any random example that would be fine with me. i am a fast learner :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look [here](http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?188261-Simple-javascript-multiplying-variables-and-displaying-in-alert-box) , and I found [this site](http://writecodeonline.com/javascript/) which I believe is good for you as well to learn.

Comment: thank you that would do the trick for me.

Comment: i will have to do some modifications though.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just hook up a javascript event handler to the website's "calculate" or "update quantity" button for the given item and use javascript to calculate the cost for the items?

Comment: i dont know javascript. :( any tutorials which could help me do this??

Comment: Danny-- all I have to say is that you've gotta learn javascript. It is totally necessary for client side programming. Here is a beginning  tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp